# Rails, No route matches {:action=>"show"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This is stumping me, made a new controller

```
class ScorecardsReviewController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_staff_user

  layout 'unbranded'

  def index
    @scorecards = Scorecard.in_review
  end
end
```

added this to the routes

```
  resources :scorecards_review
```

added a link on the home page

```
.left
  = link_to 'Home', root_path
  = link_to 'About', about_home_path
  = link_to 'Legal', disclaimer_home_path
.right
  - if current_user.try(:admin?)
    = link_to 'Agencies', agencies_path
    = link_to 'Inaccurate scorecards', reported_scorecards_path
    = link_to 'Reviews', scorecards_review_path 
  - if current_user
    = link_to 'Logout', logout_path
.clear
```

refreshed the app and i get the following

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"scorecards_review"}
```

when i rake the assets then i find all is there

```
                            POST   /scorecards_review(.:format)                                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"scorecards_review"}
      new_scorecards_review GET    /scorecards_review/new(.:format)                              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"scorecards_review"}
     edit_scorecards_review GET    /scorecards_review/:id/edit(.:format)                         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"scorecards_review"}
          scorecards_review GET    /scorecards_review/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"scorecards_review"}
                            PUT    /scorecards_review/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"scorecards_review"}
                            DELETE /scorecards_review/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"scorecards_review"}
```

i dont know what it could be??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to change scorecards_review_path to scorecards_reviews_path (with an s on the end of reviews)

Comment: Update the name (and filename) of your controller too. Because resource is used in plural.

Comment: then i get this undefined local variable or method `scorecards_reviews_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000048d1b30>:0x000000048cf650>

Comment: And update your routes.rb file:
resources :scorecards_reviews

Answer (score 4):

I think you probably want

```
resources :scorecards_reviews # plural
```

which will give you a route to the index action, which I think it what you're looking for.